Why did the lamp on a switched outlet go dim?
I have an outlet controlled by a light switch. I plug in my lamp in that outlet. A few days ago, when I turn that outlet on with my lamp plugged into, the lamp goes dim for some reason. The lamp works perfectly fine on a different outlet.
I thought the outlet was faulty but I changed the outlet and I’m still seeing the same issue after changing the outlet. Could this be light switch or could it be wiring? Been working fine since 2015. If I’m to a replace the switch is it just a basic switch?

Plug another lamp in that socket and see if that one dims.

If the lamp works on a different outlet and a diffrent lamp works/dims on that outlet, there is a problem somewhere in that circuit.  Quite likely a loose connection/bad push in connection, but loose connections cause extra heat.  Extra heat can cause fire, so turn off the breaker for that circuit, then check all connections from the outlet to the breaker.

Q="Plug another lamp in that socket and see if that one dims."   A="The lamp works perfectly fine on a different outlet."  You haven't isolated the lamp or an external power termination as the source of the problem.

I plugged in another lamp but it doesn’t dim. So what could be the issue? The original lamp dims when plugged in to that outlet but when plugged in to different outlet it works perfectly.

What's the wattage on the malfunctioning lamp vs the other lamp you're using?

Is the current switch a simple switch or a smart switch, dimmer, timer, etc.?
